# how to analyze the cpu utilization of an application

Tags: python, cpu-usage

I would like to analyze and plot the cpu utilization of an app over a period of time. The app is in Python. I would appreciate it if anyone could give me some pointers on how to this.

Comment: Look into the concept of "profiling" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming) or https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Comment: Check out psutil and perhaps Matplotlib for the plot